# how to modify vbs to archive event logs

Tags: css, vbscript

How to modify a VB script to archive event logs? I [found one VB script](http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/466-event-log-archive-script) working just fine to archive event logs to a network share folder, but I am not sure where to modify the VB script to:

1. Only collect system, application and security logs not all logs
2. How to make these archive logs with month, date and year and save them to the same folder daily and not overwrite them.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of the script here.  Links to an external source may not be available later and will reduce the value of this question for others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line ("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile") Example

("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile where LogFileName='Application'")

Add in filter for the logs you wish to backup see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/febbb896-e7fb-42c6-9b1b-6f3e3b293b22/event-viewer-log-script-only-working-for-application-event-log

OR

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/logs/event/

This should help you.

See the following altered code for your requirements, will output required logs and save to a different folder each day.

VBS

```
Dim strComputer, objDir2

Dim current: current = Now
Dim strDateStamp: strDateStamp = dateStamp(current)
strComputer = "YourServer" 
objDir2 = "Your File Server Path" & strDateStamp 
Dim objDir1: objDir1 = "\\" & strComputer & "\c$\EVT"
clearEVTLogs = "No"

Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys.FolderExists(objDir1) Then
    createDir(objDir1)

If Not filesys.FolderExists(objDir2) Then
    createDir(objDir2)
End If


strPath = objDir2 & "\"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (Backup, Security)}!\\" _
        & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile where LogFileName='Application' Or LogFileName='Security' Or LogFileName='System'")
For Each objLogfile In colLogFiles
    strCopyFile = strDateStamp & "_" & strComputer & "_" _
    & objLogFile.LogFileName & ".evt"
    strBackupFile = "c:\EVT\" & strDateStamp & "_" _
        & strComputer & "_" & objLogFile.LogFileName & ".evt"
    strBackupLog = objLogFile.BackupEventLog _
        (strBackupFile)



    Call copyAFile(objDir1, strPath, strCopyFile)


    If clearEVTLogs = "Yes" Then
        objLogFile.ClearEventLog()
    End If
Next


Function dateStamp(ByVal dt)
    Dim y, m, d
    y = Year(dt)
    m = Month(dt)
    If Len(m) = 1 Then m = "0" & m
    d = Day(dt)
    If Len(d) = 1 Then d = "0" & d
    dateStamp = y & m & d
End Function

Function copyAFile( Byval strSourceFolder, Byval strTargetFolder, _
    Byval strFileName)
    Dim objFSO, booOverWrite, strResult
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists( strSourceFolder & "\" & strFileName) _
        And UCase( strSourceFolder) <> UCase( strTargetFolder) Then
        If objFSO.FolderExists( strTargetFolder) Then
            Else
            strResult = "The destination folder does not exist!"
            'copyAFile = strResult
            Exit Function
        End If
        If objFSO.FileExists( strTargetFolder & "\" & strFileName) Then
            strResult = "The file exists, overwritten"
            booOverWrite = vbTrue
        Else
            strResult = "The file does not exist, created"
            booOverWrite = vbFalse
        End If
        objFSO.CopyFile strSourceFolder & "\" _
            & strFileName, strTargetFolder & "\", booOverWrite
    Else
        strResult = "The source file does not exist, or " _
            & "identical Source and Target folders!"
    End If

End Function


Function createDir(strDir)
    Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    wscript.echo strDir
    If Not filesys.FolderExists(strDir) Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDir)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I used this script, it works fine but just too many logs and not created a second folder for each day.

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/466-event-log-archive-script

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do a test on my server.

Comment: But it won't take \\servername\sharename, if I mapped G drive with the sharename locally on a server  such as g:\sharename then it works. Otherwise I got line 187 error:

Comment: Are your servers on the same domain, if you are running the script do you have permission to that folder, is the /sharename folder already created?

Comment: Now I have another issue, we archive security logs, it generates archive-security-2013-02-13 15 30 kind of logs. NOW we want to back all these archive logs to a central location then clear it in the local windwows\system32\winevt\logs. I am not sure whether it works. I cannto generate these logs with the above-mentioned vbs, not recognize archive-security xxxxxxxxx